# Setting up cron-tab to write logs in /var/log

Tags: bash, jenkins, cron

I am trying to setup a cron-job using jenkins on a linux machine which will run a particular job and then will create a log file in "/var/log/" and write the logs to it.
The command that I am using is:

```
ssh -i "/home/build/key.pem" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" hadoop@host_name "sudo crontab -l ; echo "2 * * * * python /home/hadoop/<file> >> /var/log/log_file.log 2>&1" | crontab -"
```

The /var and /var/log directory has 777 permission.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Whatever your question, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous*** -- you want to revert to sane permissions before you do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to install a log file which is writable by the `hadoop` user but initially empty. Then they can append to that file without affecting other files in the directory hierarchy.

You will probably also want to set up a log rotation regime to rename the log file and create a new empty file periodically.